# How Can I Change the Colour of Multiple Shapes in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've drawn quite a lot of shapes within Photoshop (Over 100) and want to change the colour of the shapes from black to another colour.

How can I do this? I don't see an option for it and can't seem to change it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each shape is probably it's own layer. double-click the layer in the white space to the right of the layer icons (or right-click and pick "blending options")

in the resultant dialog, select "color overlay" from the left-hand pane, and then double click the red color swatch to change the color.

Comment: Wouldn't necessarily work if I have 200 layers or so, and I cannot find a way to bulk-edit layers.

Comment: Merge the layers.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can change "colour overlay" in "blending options" of a shape, than "copy layer style" of the shape, select shapes you need to change and "paste layer style"
2. Select shapes and make a "smart object". Now you can work with it like you work with a simple layer. You can edit smart object by choosing "edit content" menu

Comment: guys this is the correct way using copy/paste style. I've just painted 100 layers in 5s this way

Answer (score 4):

For PS CS6:

Select each shape layer, then select a shape tool (Rectangle tool, ellipse tool, etc.) In the Options bar at the top, there is a dropdown for fill and stroke.  If you have each shape layer selected, change the fill and it will change all of them.   If you're using the eyedropper from there, you won't see the colors change until you click "OK".

Answer (score 2):

Select all the layers, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to put them all in one group.

<kbd>Double click</kbd> on the `Group` folder or <kbd>right click</kbd> on it and select `Blending Options`. Select `Color Overlay` in the list on the left, <kbd>click</kbd> on the red box to select the color you want.

No copy or pasting required. You can keep changing it by changing the color overlay in the groups blending options.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hue/saturation layer

Answer (score 0):

Set your foreground color to your desired color, then select the shape layers you want in your layer panel and hold ALT down and press backspace. You can have all the 100 layers color changed in a minute this way.